# Is this smart pointer wrapper for SDL types safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl, smart-pointers

I thought about using something like the following so I don't have to remember to explicitly call destroyer functions at the end of methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype((SDL_DestroyWindow))>
        win { SDL_CreateWindow("asdf", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN),
                  SDL_DestroyWindow };
    if (!win.get())
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "SDL_CreateWindow Error: %s",
                SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I'm not sure if it's the best approach. I'm worried that this doesn't do what I want it to do even though it looks simple enough. Are there any subtle bugs to this approach?

Comment: This code will call `SDL_DestroyWindow` when `win` gets out of scope, i.e. after `SDL_Quit`, this may not be what you want.

Comment: @Holt As `SDL_CreateWindow` is not a subsystem it should be fine. Plus there are workarounds, like using `atexit()`.

Comment: Maybe a RAII structure for SDL_init and SDL_Quit could work with that

Answer (score 3):

Introduce a new scope and you should be OK:

```
int main()
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

  {
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype((SDL_DestroyWindow))>
      win { SDL_CreateWindow("asdf", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN),
        SDL_DestroyWindow };
    if (!win.get())
    {
      SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "SDL_CreateWindow Error: %s",
          SDL_GetError());
      return 1;
    }
  } // win destroyed before SQL_Quit

  SDL_Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use RAII even more:

```
struct SDL_RAII
{
    SDL_RAII() { SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); }

    ~SDL_RAII() noexcept {
        try {
            SDL_Quit();
        } catch (...) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }

    SDL_RAII(const SDL_RAII&) = delete;
    SDL_RAII(SDL_RAII&&) = delete;
    SDL_RAII& operator=(const SDL_RAII&) = delete;
    SDL_RAII& operator=(SDL_RAII&&) = delete;
};
```

and be DRY by factorizing the deleter:

```
template <typename Object, void (*DeleterFun)(Object*)>
struct Deleter
{
    void operator() (Object* obj) const noexcept
    {
        try {
            DeleterFun(obj);
        } catch (...) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
};

template <typename Object, void (*DeleterFun)(Object*)>
using UniquePtr = std::unique_ptr<Object, Deleter<Object, DeleterFun>>;
```

Then, some types for SDL:

```
using Unique_SDL_Window = UniquePtr<SDL_Window, SDL_DestroyWindow>;
using Unique_SDL_Surface = UniquePtr<SDL_Surface, SDL_FreeSurface>;
// ...
```

And finally:

```
int main()
{
    SDL_RAII SDL_raii;

    Unique_SDL_Window win{ SDL_CreateWindow("asdf", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)};

    if (!win.get())
    {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION,
                     "SDL_CreateWindow Error: %s",
                     SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go in the direction of making it "look & feel like modern C++", you could combine the following two techniques:

- scope guard (for `SDL_Quit`),
- specialised default deleter (for `SDL_Window`).

#### Scope guard

A *scope guard* is a dummy object that calls the supplied function object from its destructor. Allocating it on the stack will make it call the destructor when it leaves the defining scope; doing that in the `main()` function means that it will run on program exit. For more details, there is a [nice talk by Andrei Alexandrescu](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C) about this (the part about scope guards starts at 1:05:14).

The implementation (from the presentation, mostly):

```
template<class Fn>
class ScopeGuard {
 public:
  explicit ScopeGuard(Fn fn) noexcept
      : fn_(std::move(fn)),
        active_(true) {}

  ScopeGuard() = delete;
  ScopeGuard(const ScopeGuard &) = delete;
  ScopeGuard(ScopeGuard &&that) noexcept
      : fn_(std::move(that.fn_)),
        active_(that.active_) {
    that.dismiss();
  }

  ScopeGuard &operator=(const ScopeGuard &) = delete;

  ~ScopeGuard() {
    if (active_) {
      try {
        fn_();
      } catch (...) {
        // The destructor must not throw.
      }
    }
  }

  void dismiss() noexcept {
    active_ = false;
  }

 private:
  Fn fn_;
  bool active_;
};
```

Instantiating the class directly wouldn't be very convenient, but on functions we get type inference:

```
// Provided purely for type inference.
template<class Fn>
ScopeGuard<Fn> scopeGuard(Fn fn) {
  return ScopeGuard<Fn>(std::move(fn));
}
```

To create a scope guard, you'll simply call `scopeGuard(lambda)` where `lambda` is the function you want to run on leaving the scope. The actual type will be inferred; we're not interested in it anyway.

```
// Will call SDL_Quit() once 'guard' goes out of scope.
auto guard = scopeGuard([] { SDL_Quit(); });
```

#### Specialised default deleter

[You can specialise `std::default_deleter`](https://philwrightdev.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/providing-a-custom-deleter-to-stdunique_ptr/), by defining the following function object (in this case, a struct with `operator()`):

```
template<>
struct std::default_delete<SDL_Window> {
  void operator()(SDL_Window *p) { SDL_DestroyWindow(p); }
};
```

You could do this for most types in SDL, since they have exactly one "destroy" function. (You might want to wrap that in a macro.)

The nice thing about this is that as of SDL 2.0.x, `SDL_Window` and other types we get them from `SDL2/SDL.h` are incomplete types, i.e., you can't call `sizeof(SDL_Window)` on them. This means that the compiler won't be able to `delete` them out-of-the box (for that it needs `sizeof`), and therefore you won't be able to instantiate a (plain) `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window>`.

With the specialised deleter, however, `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window>` *will* work, and will call `SDL_DestroyWindow` in the destructor.

#### Result

The result, using the definitions above, is quite a boilerplate-free example of RAII:

```
int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    auto quit_scope_guard = scopeGuard([] { SDL_Quit(); });

    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window> win(SDL_CreateWindow("asdf", 100, 100,
                                    640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN));
    if (!win) {
        // ~quit_scope_guard will call SDL_Quit().
        return 1;
    }

    // ~win will call SDL_DestroyWindow(win.get()).
    // ~quit_scope_guard will call SDL_Quit().
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the `SDL_Init` and `SDL_Quit` as an RAII class:

```
struct SDL_exception {
  int value;
};
struct SDL {
  SDL(uint32_t arg) {
    if(int err = SDL_INIT(arg)) {
      throw SDL_exeption{err};
    }
  }
  ~SDL() {
    SDL_Quit();
  }
};
```

next, create a smart-pointer-maker:

```
template<class Create, class Destroy>
struct SDL_factory_t;
template<class Type, class...Args, class Destroy>
struct SDL_factory_t<Type*(*)(Args...), Destroy> {
  using Create=Type*(*)(Args...);
  Create create;
  Destroy destroy;

  using type=Type;
  using ptr = std::unique_ptr<Type, Destroy>;

  ptr operator()(Args&&...args)const {
    return {create(std::forward<Args>(args)...), destroy};
  }
};
template<class Create, class Destroy>
constexpr SDL_factory_t<Create,Destroy>
SDL_factory(Create create, Destroy destroy) {
  return {create, destroy};
};
```

this places the instrumentation to define destruction at one spot, not at every spot you create the thing.

For each type you want to wrap, just do this:

```
constexpr auto SDL_Window_Factory = SDL_factory(SDL_CreateWindow, SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

and now your code becomes:

```
int main()
{
  SDL init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  auto win = SDL_Window_Factory("asdf", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  if (!win) {
    SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "SDL_CreateWindow Error: %s",
            SDL_GetError());
    return 1;
  }
}
```

which is *much* less noisy in the body of `main`, no?

As a bonus, the window (and anything else) is destroyed prior to the SDL quit command.

We can add more exception-based error handling in the factory, or even make it an option somehow, where `.notthrowing( args... )` doesn't throw, while `( args... )` does, or some such.

Comment: I don't understand your last edit. In addition `Args&&...args` is no longer forwarding reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at how instances of the types in the SDL library are created and destroyed, you will realize that they are usually created by calling a function that returns a pointer to the newly created instance. They are destroyed by calling a function that takes a pointer to the instance to destroy. For example:

- An `SDL_Window` instance is created by calling [`SDL_CreateWindow()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow), which returns an `SDL_Window *`, and destroyed with [`SDL_DestroyWindow()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyWindow), which takes an `SDL_Window *`.
- An `SDL_Renderer` instance is created by calling [`SDL_CreateRenderer()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer), which returns an `SDL_Renderer *`, and destroyed with [`SDL_DestroyRenderer()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_DestroyRenderer), which takes an `SDL_Renderer *`.

By taking advantage of the observation above, we can define a class template, `scoped_resource`, that implements the RAII idiom for the SDL types. First, we define the following convenience function templates that act as type traits for functions like `SDL_CreateWindow()` and `SDL_DestroyWindow()`:

```
template<typename, typename...> struct creator_func;

template<typename TResource, typename... TArgs>
struct creator_func<TResource*(*)(TArgs...)> {
   using resource_type = TResource;
   static constexpr auto arity = sizeof...(TArgs);
};

template<typename> struct deleter_func;

template<typename TResource>
struct deleter_func<void(*)(TResource*)> {
   using resource_type = TResource;
};
```

Then, the `scoped_resource` class template:

```
#include <memory> // std::unique_ptr

template<auto FCreator, auto FDeleter>
class scoped_resource {
public:
   using resource_type = typename creator_func<decltype(FCreator)>::resource_type;

   template<typename... TArgs>
   scoped_resource(TArgs... args): ptr_(FCreator(args...), FDeleter) {}

   operator resource_type*() const noexcept { return ptr_.get(); }

   resource_type* get() const noexcept { return ptr_.get(); }

private:
   using deleter_pointee = typename deleter_func<decltype(FDeleter)>::resource_type;
   static_assert(std::is_same_v<resource_type, deleter_pointee>);

   std::unique_ptr<resource_type, decltype(FDeleter)> ptr_;
};
```

The following types can be now introduced with type aliases:

```
using Window   = scoped_resource<SDL_CreateWindow,   SDL_DestroyWindow>;
using Renderer = scoped_resource<SDL_CreateRenderer, SDL_DestroyRenderer>;
```

Finally, you could create an `SDL_Window` instance by constructing a `Window` object. You pass to `Window`'s constructor the same arguments you would pass to `SDL_CreateWindow()`:

```
Window win("MyWindow", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, 0);
```

When the object `win` is destroyed, `SDL_DestroyWindow()` will be called on the contained `SDL_Window *`.

---

Note, however, that in some cases – for example, when creating an `SDL_Surface`, you may need to wrap the original creator function inside a function of your own and pass this function as the creator for `scoped_resource`. This is because `SDL_LoadBMP` may correspond to a macro that expands to a function call instead of function.

You may also want to create a custom creator function for every type to be able to throw an exception if the creator function fails.